# Entity Framework - Unable to update the EntitySet Binary data

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework

Entity Framework is throwing error:

```
Test 'WorkerProcessService.Test.WorkerProcessMonitorTests.Test' failed: System.Data.UpdateException : Unable to update the EntitySet 'Processor' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlGen.DmlSqlGenerator.ExpressionTranslator.Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
 at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbScanExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor visitor)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlGen.DmlSqlGenerator.GenerateInsertSql(DbInsertCommandTree tree, SqlVersion sqlVersion, List`1& parameters)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlGen.SqlGenerator.GenerateSql(DbCommandTree tree, SqlVersion sqlVersion, List`1& parameters, CommandType& commandType, HashSet`1& paramsToForceNonUnicode)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree commandTree)
 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(UpdateTranslator translator, Dictionary`2 identifierValues)
 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
 at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
 WorkerProcessMonitor.cs(79,0): at Star.Portal.Services.WorkerProcessMonitor.AddComponent(Byte[] component)
 WorkerProcessMonitorTests.cs(55,0): at WorkerProcessService.Test.WorkerProcessMonitorTests.Test()
```

I have a table like, and auto generated edmx model

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Processor](
  [ProcessorID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [ProcessorDLL] [varbinary](max) NULL,
)
```

The folowing fails to update

```
public void AddComponent(byte[] component)
        {
            Processor p = new Processor()
                              {
                                  ProcessorDLL = component,
                              };
             using (var cn = GetWorkerProcessEntities())
             {

                 cn.AddToProcessors(p);
                 cn.SaveChanges();
             }

        }
```

The question is: Do I have to do anything specific to implement binary storage in sql server?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-ado-net/21686/EF-or-LINQtoSQL-and-VarBinary-Max

Comment: What is `cn,AddToProcessors(p);` Doing exactly?

Comment: have you set auto increament in Processor's ProcessorID???

Answer (score 1):

simple answer... No, I am storing images in a table with the same datatype (varbinary(max)).

Not knowing much about your code, i have simple test using local DB.
this is my POCO and DBcontext. ( I dont use auto generated edmx )

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
public class Processor
{
    public int ProcessorId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProcessorDLL { get; set; }
}
public class ProcessorConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Processor>
{
    public ProcessorConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(i => i.ProcessorId);

        ToTable("Processor", "dbo");
    }
}
//DbContext
public class myContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Processor> Processors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProcessorConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Then when I add a new Processor, I use this

```
public void test()
    {
        myContext context = new myContext();

        Processor p = new Processor
        {
            ProcessorDLL = getSomeRandomByteArray()
        };

        context.Processors.Add(p);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

and in my table:

```
ProcessorID: 1
ProcessorDLL: 0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010200...
```

Hope this helped.